# Como abrir uma activity a partir de uma notificação em java no android?

Tags: java, android

Como abrir uma activity clicando na notificação. O detalhe é que eu quero que ela reabra novamente mesmo se ela estiver aberta, a fim de atualizar os dados da mesma.
estou usando:

```
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

O código acima faz uso da flag `UPDATE_CURRENT` que atualiza ao invés de abrir uma nova activity, ele vai atualizar os dados atuais da activity. Ou seja, a flag verificar se a `intent` e então vai abrir ela apenas atualizando os dados.

Comment: @Sergio, sim. O código é o mesmo do Emerson. A única coisa que eu adicionei foi uma `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` que vai verificar se a activity existe e se existir, atualizará os dados da `activity`, que é o que o Emerson deseja. Citação dele: `O detalhe é que eu quero que ela reabra novamente mesmo se ela estiver aberta, a fim de atualizar os dados da mesma`. A flag vai fazer exatamente isto.

Comment: valeu cara, era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Emerson, de nada! haha. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
PendingIntent notificationIntent = preparePendingIntent(context,stringValue,valueBoolean);

PendingIntent preparePendingIntent(Context context,String valueString,boolean valueBoolean) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    //Passando Valores para Activity
    args.putBoolean("Key", valueBoolean);
    args.putString("Key", valueString);

    intent.putExtras(args);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(0,
            context, 
            intent, 
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    return pendingIntent;
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt, Rafael. Respostas com somente códigos e links são 'ok', mas ficam melhores ainda quando você fornece contexto a eles. Explique porque seu código responde a pergunta. Qualquer dúvida: [answer]